# Nginx/Guicorn 502s under load

Tags: python, nginx, websocket, gunicorn

I have an application serving WebSockets that proxies to Gunicorn using Nginx. I am seeing when a bunch of clients (say 30) are already busy interacting with the server, new attempts to connect to the proxy are failing with 502 errors.

I understand this could just be load, but what is strange is these 502s happen always after 10 seconds (Nginx logs). I've upped every timeout both in Nginx and Guicorn but always its ~ 10 seconds.

Need some guidance as to what controls that timeout and what I might change to get the 502s to go away.

Also, worth noting, if the 30 clients just connect and don't start interacting with the websocket, I can connect 100 more clients just fine.

Comment: Have you tried setting up more workers? Do you use threading or asyncio? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Pure async. More (or less) workers seem to have no effect. Workload does have affect, 30 working clients returning 5k rows cause the problem slower than 30 clients returning 80k rows. This is a huge app, working on boiling it down. Just the 10 seconds make no sense as I can't see any part of the stack that doesn't have a timeout set to something larger.

Comment: Without a proper example to reproduce the behavior you are complaining about, we can't do much.